# How to close alert dialog android?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have some alert dialog, my question is how to close alert dialog box when I clicked cross (X) on the right top corner (without setNegative button).

```
imgmain.setImageResource(imgID);
        imgmain.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {          
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                /*Intent MyIntentDetailItem=new Intent(getBaseContext(), ViewDetailItemFullscreen.class);
                Other_class.setItemCode(timgName);
                startActivity(MyIntentDetailItem);*/

                LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(ViewDetailItem.this);
                final View inputdialogcustom = li.inflate(R.layout.activity_view_detail_item_fullscreen2, null);                
                final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(ViewDetailItem.this); 

                ImageView btnclose = (ImageView) inputdialogcustom.findViewById(R.id.btnclosepopup);
                btnclose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {

//DOING SOMETHING
                    }
                });

       }
}
```

Comment: Is it customized Alert ?

Comment: yes it is customize alert, I am using image (x) to close the alert dialog

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have `X` with an image then you can do it following way,

```
private static AlertDialog.Builder alert; // at class level
```

rest of the code is same

```
alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(ViewDetailItem.this); 
btnclose.setOnClickListener ( new OnClickListener () 
{
     @Override 
     public void onClick ( View view )
     {
          alert.dismiss(); // Add this line in your code.
     }
});
```

Comment: it is not defined for the type AlertDialog.Builder alert

Comment: it is same, I cannot get DISMISS option when I press Ctrl+Space to see option of alert.

Comment: This seems to be an interesting problem, can you send me your code by email  ?

Comment: Thanks Kedarnath, you just look for "// YOU CAN WRITE CODE HERE" to add your source code, here the link : http://pastebin.com/YNkskB8t

Comment: No, I can not do like that, if it is possible then send me your full project code.

Comment: It is there in my profile page. It's gmail one. Here in office , I can not access gmail, so I will open it at home in night.

Answer (score 0):

You can close dialog using dismiss fucntion `myalertdialog.dismiss()`

Comment: it is not defined for the type AlertDialog.Builder alert

Comment: what type of dialog it is?

Comment: customized alert dialog

Answer (score 0):

Use finish() to exit from the alert dialog...